# How to retrieve last modification time of files stored in Org?

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, cli, sync, diff

Currently I am using `sf project retrieve start` to retrieve files stored inside the Salesforce Org.

Is it possible to retrieve the file modification times of these files as well? I am working on a tool that would use these.

So far I didn't find a solution yet. I've looked in the CLI help and searched the web, but no solutions yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metadata retrieve API doesn't include timestamps of the metadata. Use `sf org metadata list` or `sf data query --use-tooling-api` if you want this kind of metadata.